# Does it make sense to use the Spearman-Brown correction (prediction / prophecy) formula with Kendall's Tau correlation coefficient?

Tags: reliability, psychometrics, spearman-brown

The Spearman-Brown prophecy formula is used to estimate the increase in reliability that is obtained when more measurements are taken (and aggregated) from the same construct. Reliability is the correlation between true score and measured score - typically defined as the Pearson correlation.

Does the S-B formula also work with Kendall (and/or Spearman) correlation?

Comment: Browne's (1910) argument/derivation would appear to apply equally to the Spearman correlation (it's just based on arguments relating to variances / sums of squares and covariances / sums of cross products), and indeed Browne seems to switch between Pearson and Spearman correlations as he progresses through his examples without betraying any concern (at least not that I noticed on a quick look at the paper). I don't see that the argument would carry to the Kendall correlation in general (though it's possible I just missed thinking of a way to justify it).